# Struggling to make vegetarian souffle pancakes with whey protein

Tags: eggs, pancakes, whey

So,I have been trying to use whey protein 80 percent concentration to make a souffle pancake. I want to replace the egg whites with whey protein concentrate. I tried but the mixture won't whip,my friend who uses same concentrate (different brand) it is whipping. I can't afford the brand right now. But the ingredient is supposed to be the same.

I tried
6 gms- whey protein
30 ml- cold water. (I even tried adding 1/4tsp xantham gum).

And tried to whisk it.

I looked up online but could not find anything

Can anyone tell how to substitute egg whites with whey protein.

Comment: How long did you whisk it for, and are you whisking by hand? It can take several minutes using an electric mixer to get some things to whip.

Comment: Is whey (made from milk) more vegetarian than eggs?

Comment: It is considered vegetarian . Why do you ask

Comment: I used electric whisker,for 10 minutes. My friend got it in 2-3 mins max. I caved in and got the expensive brand. It worked. Am participating in a food fair,so I wanted to get the more economical option

Answer (score 1):

> the ingredient is supposed to be the same

"The same" is a stretchy term. Imagine a freshly picked cob of corn, with the husk still on, then some maize semolina, then a pack of cornflour, then a tortilla, then a bottle of high fructose corn syrup. They are all made of "the same" thing - 100% maize. But because they were processed in different ways, they behave totally different during cooking, and you cannot substitute one of them for the other.

If your brand of protein doesn't whip, then there is nothing you can do about it. You'll have to find a brand that whips, and use that one. If you don't want to use the same one as your friend's, you can test out other brands, until you find one that happens to work. Maybe first write to customer support to inquire whether a specific brand will whip, then you can save some tedious testing.